# Lego LOTR - Catapult glitch in Cirith Ungol

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s, lego-lord-of-the-rings

It's been documented elsewhere that the Lego LOTR game has some glitches. One of these is that on the Cirith Ungol level, when you need to find disguises for Frodo and Sam, sometimes the catapult does not launch.

I am currently hitting this on an Xbox Series X. The posts I've seen about it are generally older, so I think they were probably for the original 360 or Xbox One. The solution others have mentioned is generally reloading the game in various ways. I've tried:

1. restarting the level
2. quitting to the main menu then restarting
3. quitting to the Xbox home screen then going back into the game
4. rebooting the Xbox
5. many combinations of these things

No luck. The only thing I haven't tried is redoing the entire save, which I don't want to do because this is near-ish the end.

I did see some posts mention that the game has a cache, and when this cache fills up, some of these glitches start appearing. The thing I am afraid of is that the Xbox Series X somehow prevents the cache from ever being cleared.

So, any ideas to save my game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after posting this I thought of one more thing! I removed the game from the "Quick Resume" list, which forced the game to actually unload and reload. I think this is what it needed to force refresh the cache, because after loading it up again it worked right away. Phew!